# How do I kill a screen if I know the name of it?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a screen named 'foo' that I started using the command

```
screen -S foo -d -m  my_command_goes_here.
```

I want to put this in cron, and restart it nightly by killing the screen.  The reason I'm using a screen is my command starts up several other procs and this will ensure they all exit.

So... what is the command to kill sceen 'foo'?

Thanks!

Comment: What commands are you running that you require screen to have them properly exit?

Answer (score 18):

`screen -S foo -X quit`

From the man page:

```
-X  Send the specified command to a running screen session.
...
quit    Kill all windows and terminate screen.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

screen -S foo -X kill

I would be cautious tho, depending on what you're running and the state that it's in, this may not kill the processes running in screen, and maybe cause file system instability if it has any files open (i don't know for sure, i'm just assuming)

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work.

Comment: worked for me, was on ubuntu. But I only had one window open in screen.  Should have done more testing.

Comment: only reason why I can't see this working is if you have more than 1 screen session named `foo`, use `screen -list` to get a list of current running sessions.